# Lenovo T14 AMD dual screen problems

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I am running a Lenovo T14 gen 1 AMD with Ubuntu 20.04 and 5.8.0-rc7 kernel, AMD driver 20.20 is  installed. My goal is to run 2 displays with the Lenovo Thunderbolt3 dock (updated it yesterday with a window computer), which is connected on the tb3 port of the laptop. The displays I am using are Dell 27" and a Dell 34" both connected through DP.

Right now I have to have both displays connected in order to get the 34" one running in full resolution, otherwise it will only work in 2560x1440.
When trying to activate the 27" display I am getting the following error in syslog:

```
Aug 14 10:16:30 Vmax /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2308]: (EE) AMDGPU(0): failed to set mode: No space left on device
Aug 14 10:16:30 Vmax /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2308]: (EE) AMDGPU(0): drmmode_do_crtc_dpms cannot get last vblank counter
```

Xrandr output shows that they are recognized well:

```
eDP connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.03 +
   1680x1050     60.03  
   1280x1024     60.03  
   1440x900      60.03  
   1280x800      60.03  
   1280x720      60.03  
   1024x768      60.03  
   800x600       60.03  
   640x480       60.03  
HDMI-A-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-3 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   2560x1440     59.95 +
   1920x1200     59.88  
   1920x1080     60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94    24.00    23.98  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DisplayPort-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-5 connected primary 3440x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 800mm x 335mm
   3440x1440     59.97*+  49.99  
   2560x1440     59.95  
   2560x1080     60.00  
   1720x1440     60.00  
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DisplayPort-6 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Dmesg has the following errors:

```
❯ sudo dmesg | grep -i amdgpu
[    1.111933] [drm] amdgpu kernel modesetting enabled.
[    1.112056] amdgpu: Topology: Add CPU node
[    1.112153] fb0: switching to amdgpudrmfb from EFI VGA
[    1.112265] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
[    1.112291] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: enabling device (0006 -> 0007)
[    1.112404] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: Trusted Memory Zone (TMZ) feature disabled as experimental (default)
[    1.130223] amdgpu: ATOM BIOS: 113-RENOIR-025
[    1.130320] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: VRAM: 512M 0x000000F400000000 - 0x000000F41FFFFFFF (512M used)
[    1.130322] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: GART: 1024M 0x0000000000000000 - 0x000000003FFFFFFF
[    1.130324] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: AGP: 267419648M 0x000000F800000000 - 0x0000FFFFFFFFFFFF
[    1.130705] [drm] amdgpu: 512M of VRAM memory ready
[    1.130709] [drm] amdgpu: 3072M of GTT memory ready.
[    1.133742] [drm:dm_dmub_sw_init [amdgpu]] *ERROR* DMUB firmware loading failed: -2
[    1.968945] amdgpu: SMU is initialized successfully!
[    2.018276] [drm:dm_helpers_dp_write_dpcd [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to find connector for link!
[    2.018875] [drm:dm_helpers_dp_write_dpcd [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to find connector for link!
[    2.019071] [drm:dm_helpers_dp_write_dpcd [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to find connector for link!
[    2.230614] amdgpu: Topology: Add dGPU node [0x1636:0x1002]
[    2.230619] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: SE 1, SH per SE 1, CU per SH 8, active_cu_number 7
[    2.231360] fbcon: amdgpudrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    2.868665] [drm:mod_hdcp_add_display_to_topology [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to add display topology, DTM TA is not initialized.
[    2.889838] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: fb0: amdgpudrmfb frame buffer device
[    2.910842] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: ring gfx uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 0
[    2.910845] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.0 uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 0
[    2.910847] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.0 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 0
[    2.910849] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.0 uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 0
[    2.910850] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.0 uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 0
[    2.910852] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.1 uses VM inv eng 7 on hub 0
[    2.910853] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.1 uses VM inv eng 8 on hub 0
[    2.910855] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.1 uses VM inv eng 9 on hub 0
[    2.910857] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.1 uses VM inv eng 10 on hub 0
[    2.910858] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: ring kiq_2.1.0 uses VM inv eng 11 on hub 0
[    2.910860] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: ring sdma0 uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 1
[    2.910862] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_dec uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 1
[    2.910864] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_enc0 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 1
[    2.910866] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_enc1 uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 1
[    2.910868] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: ring jpeg_dec uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 1
[    2.936802] [drm] Initialized amdgpu 3.38.0 20150101 for 0000:07:00.0 on minor 0
[    3.975921] [drm:mod_hdcp_add_display_to_topology [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to add display topology, DTM TA is not initialized.
[   10.617947] snd_hda_intel 0000:07:00.1: bound 0000:07:00.0 (ops amdgpu_dm_audio_component_bind_ops [amdgpu])
[   23.376428] [drm:mod_hdcp_add_display_to_topology [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to add display topology, DTM TA is not initialized.
[   46.671895] [drm:mod_hdcp_add_display_to_topology [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to add display topology, DTM TA is not initialized.
[   66.004357] [drm:mod_hdcp_add_display_to_topology [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to add display topology, DTM TA is not initialized.
[   73.940064] [drm:mod_hdcp_add_display_to_topology [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to add display topology, DTM TA is not initialized.
[ 1245.413179] [drm:mod_hdcp_add_display_to_topology [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to add display topology, DTM TA is not initialized.
[ 1697.709771] [drm:mod_hdcp_add_display_to_topology [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to add display topology, DTM TA is not initialized.
[ 6346.769224] [drm:mod_hdcp_add_display_to_topology [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to add display topology, DTM TA is not initialized.
```

How can I get rid of the errors and make this setup work?

Comment: Hi, do you have a second GPU ? What is the answer of ``lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"`` ?

Comment: There is just one gpu it seems. The output of the command is: 
`❯ lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"
07:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir (rev d1)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Renoir
 Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
`

Answer (score 1):

The AMD version don't have thunderbolt so it won't work with the TB3 docking.

Answer (score 0):

Same laptop same problem, on Manjaro Linux

```
Linux thinkpad-t14 5.7.19-2-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Aug 28 20:22:12 UTC 2020 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I solved it by using an HDMI cable instead of usb-c to HDMI converter to connect my external monitor. I'll probably buy an HDMI splitter and hope both my external monitors work from the laptop's HDMI out.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a Plugable Thunderbolt 3 / USB-C dock along with a Sabrent USB-C dual HDMI adapter. I have keyboard, mouse, etc... connected to the dock, along with a single monitor. When using USB-C instead of Thunderbolt on the dock it will push two 1080p monitors or a single 4K monitor, on TB3 it will push both. The strange thing that I run into which I can't solve is the monitor will not wake with the keyboard, mouse, etc... I have to unplug and plug the USB-C connection. I opted for magnetic USB-C connector so I can just do that easily. The USB-C Sabrent dongle works from sleep. I plugged both monitors and was able to get AMD FreeSync (which I'm not sure is exactly) show up on my screen since the monitors support that.